# WPF observable collection

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection` in the view model which is binded to a `DataGrid` in the view but it's `CollectionChanged` event is not triggered if someone add a new row or if someone modifies the already existing row.

```
    public void onCollectionEventFired(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {

        }
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        { 

        }
    }


    #region Properties
    public ObservableCollection<Expenses> expenses
    {
        get
        {
            if (_expenses == null)
            {
                _expenses = new ObservableCollection<Expenses>();
                _expenses.CollectionChanged += onCollectionEventFired;
            }

            return _expenses;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your XAML?

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event in your ViewModel instead of your collection's getter.

```
public class MyVM
   {
      public MyVM()
      {
         this.expenses.CollectionChanged += onCollectionEventFired;
      }
   }
```

And you need a `set{}` to assign changes to the collection.

```
public ObservableCollection<Expenses> expenses
    {
        get
        {
            if (_expenses == null)
            {
                _expenses = new ObservableCollection<Expenses>();
            }

            return _expenses;
        }
        set
        {
            _expenses = value;
        }
    }
```